# Twitter query result returns only 15 tweets

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using the twitter api in java to query tweets containing certain hashtags.

Example:

```
Query query = new Query("%23superbowl since:2013-12-21");
QueryResult result;
result = twitter.search(query);
List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
```

Array size is only 15. How do I change the max number of tweets returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set count in your query as:

```
query.setCount(100);
```

But remember, as per Twitter4j doc it allows max up to 100 only. You can check it [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setCount%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

query.[setCount](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html#setCount%28int%29)() is the key:

The default count is -1 in the library, hence it won't put the parameter in the request.

With no parameter present Twitter defaults to 15, see [count paremeter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets).